# How to send array of strings in query parameters of get request in postman

Tags: get, yaml, postman, postman-mocks

I have postman mock server with collection, and one of the requests has parameter with type `array`.

Here is the definition for this query parameter in the API ymal file:

```
- name: departureAirports
          required: false
          in: query
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
              pattern: ^[A-Z]{3}$
```

When I send this request from postman with value like this `["123"]`

[image]

, I got this error:

`The query parameter "departureAirports" needs to be of type array, but we found "["123"]"`

[image]

So, How can I send array of strings in the query parameters in get request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the value of parameter departureAirports array like

```
departureAirports[1]:1
departureAirports[2]:2
departureAirports[3]:3
```

Comment: you can send the parameters in api as

Comment: query string in api url